# xpath finding two elements in a tr

Tags: testing, selenium, xpath, testng

If I have

```
<tr>
 <td> John </td>
 <td> Smith </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td> John </td>
 <td> Bloggs </td>
</tr>
```

To find John using xpath I can use:

```
//tr[td//text()[contains(., 'John')]]"
```

However I would like to find the row that has elements both John and Smith?

```
//tr[td//text()[contains(., 'John')] && td//text()[contains(., 'Smith')]]"
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `//tr[td[contains(., 'John')] and td[contains(., 'Smith')]]`.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `//tr[contains(., 'John') and contains(., 'Smith')]`